# Proper way to create stripe charge in django/python

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm currently integrating stripe into a django project. I followed the tutorial on [stripe website](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges) using the code samples but I'm not sure if they are production ready. This is the most delicate part of the application and I want to be sure it's done right. Currently, I have something that looks similar to this.

```
if new_order_form.is_valid():
    new_order = new_order_form.save(commit=False)
    new_order.total = 10
    new_order.order_number = generate_order_number(8)
    try:
      charge = stripe.Charge.create(
          amount=1000, # new_order.total * 100
          currency="usd",
          source=token,
          description="Example charge"
      )
      new_order.charge_id = charge.id
    except stripe.error.CardError, e:
      # The card has been declined
      pass

    new_order.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
return redirect(request, 'new_order.html' context)
```

**Edit:**
My concerns are:

- Could there ever be a scenario where the card is charged twice?
- Could there ever be a scenario where the order is created and saved
  but the charge was not successful?
- Where should the order be created and saved?

Comment: What is the problem you are hitting with this code? Are there errors when you run it?

Comment: I'm still testing for different scenarios and haven't run into any problems yet.

Comment: There is no question in your post, so it cannot really be answered. To get a specific answer, ask a specific question. With the provided code it is difficult to tell what you would like feedback on, as there are hardcoded values, and no explanation of what it should do, or what cases you are trying to handle.

Comment: I understand that. I've edited the post to add more info.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what we use in our project, hope it helps!!

```
try:
    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
      amount={{amount}}, 
      currency="usd",
      customer={{customer}},
      description={{description}},
      metadata={{this.id}}
  )
except stripe.error.CardError as e:
    # Problem with the card
    pass
except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
    # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
    pass
except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
    # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe API
    pass
except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
    # Authentication Error: Authentication with Stripe API failed (maybe you changed API keys recently)
    pass
except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
    # Network communication with Stripe failed
    pass
except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
    # Stripe Error
    pass
else:
    #success
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [django stripe payments,](https://github.com/pinax/django-stripe-payments) or using their code for reference.

Comment: what advantages does this have over just using the code snippet from the stripe tutorial. After including the above code snippet, , they basically wrote, "That's it! If the charge creation request succeeds, and doesn't throw an error, the card has been successfully charged. You will receive your money in seven days." I'll look at their code for reference. Thanks